# error when trying to test my google cloud function that is triggered by a pubsub event

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments, google-cloud-pubsub

I built a google cloud function that is triggered by a pubsub event (in order to schedule it later on using cloud scheduler). Basically, i want to retrieve data from stripe and then load then into BigQuery. Below is my code source.

```
import json
import stripe
import pandas as pd
import io
from google.cloud import bigquery

def get_stripe_info(event, context):
    if 'data' in event :
        stripe.api_key = "my stripe key"
        data = stripe.Invoice.list(limit=1)
        result={}
        data_json =[]
        result["customer"] = data["data"][0]["customer"]
        result["amount_paid"] = data["data"][0]["amount_paid"]
        data_json.append(result)
        jsonStr = json.dumps(data_json)
        df = pd.DataFrame(data_json)
        json_data = df.to_json(orient = 'records', lines = True)
        stringio_data = io.StringIO(json_data)

        bq_client = Client()
        dataset_id = 'myDataset'
        table_id = 'myTable'
        dataset_ref = bq_client.dataset(dataset_id)
        table_ref = dataset_ref.table(table_id)
        job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
        job_config.schema = [
            bigquery.SchemaField("customer", "STRING"),
            bigquery.SchemaField("amount_paid", "INT64")
        ]
        #job_config.skip_leading_rows = 1
        job_config.source_format = bigquery.SourceFormat.NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON
        job_config.autodetect = True

        job = bq_client.load_table_from_file(
            stringio_data,
            table_ref,
            location="us",  # Must match the destination dataset location.
            job_config=job_config,
        )  # API request
        job.result()
```

I'm getting this error when I tried to publish a message on pubsub topic in order to trigger my function. Any help please!

[image: error log]

Comment: Did you test your function with a dummy json? In addition, is it normal that you never use the data value embedded in the event dict?

Comment: I tried it's not working either. I have a same error.

Comment: I tried your code snippet and used dummy a json for [event](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/object) and [data](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/list). I created a table with the schema you provided and I'm able to load data in bigquery. Where exactly is the error in the code that you encounter?

Comment: I manually published a message with a string "ok" to trigger the cloud function and I got the error. I also tried to test the function directly in cloud function interface in Google Cloud and I got exactly the same error. Really don't know what is going wrong.

Comment: How did you structure your message to trigger the function in cloud function interface? I used `{ "data": {"topic":"test-topic","message":"ok"} } ` and this is being accepted by the `event` properly. Also can you edit your post to include how you are sending messages to the topic via pub/sub and cloud function interface?

Comment: I was just testing the trigger to be sure that my function works fine. I'm planning to schedule a Google cloud scheduler job to be executed every 2 hours in a day and its target will be my PubSub topic.

Comment: I see. You can [open a support ticket](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/procedures#create_a_support_case) at the GCP console for this to be checked by the support team.